# How to measure size (KB) of an interstitial received from publicity SDK

Tags: android, download, interstitial, measure

First i apologyse for my poor english.

Our company is using a publicity SDK wich is responsible for showing interstitial at launch, during splashscreen. We don't have access directly to the view that is loaded. After initialization with app id in Application class the basic workflow is :

```
    private MNGAdsFactory mngAdsBannerAdsFactory;

    // init intertitial factory
    mngAdsInterstitialAdsFactory = new MNGAdsFactory(this);

    // set intertitial listener
    mngAdsInterstitialAdsFactory.setInterstitialListener(this);

    if (mngAdsInterstitialAdsFactory.createInterstitial()) {
        //Wait callBack from interstitial listener
    }else{
        //adsFactory can not handle your request
    }
```

And the success callback

```
@Override
        public void interstitialDidLoad() {
            Log.d(TAG, "interstitial did load");
        }
```

Here is my problem. I want to measure the size (KB) of the interstitial displayed on screen in order to monitor some abuses. 
Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance.